# Listing related data in custom email template via component

Tags: apex, soql, visualforce-component, email-template

I am creating an email template which will be sent to individual contacts, the template needs to list rows from a related object.
I have created the relevant component and class which I believe would have achieved this however I have come across some issues:

**relatedTo Contact details are not loaded**
I get the following error when trying to save the email template when using my Contact fields

> Error: Invalid field Contact for SObject Account

The line in question is `{!relatedTo.Contact.Name}`

**Email Template:**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="My email subject" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

    <p><apex:outputText value="{!TODAY()}" /></p>

    <p>REF: <apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.Name}" /></p>

    <p>Dear {!relatedTo.Contact.Name},</p>

    <c:ORCLetter_Component acctId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you used:

```
{!relatedTo.Contact.Name}
```

presumes that there is a lookup relationship from Account to Contact. But there isn't. There is a lookup relationship from Contact to Account.  That is, `relatedTo` references the `relatedToType`

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="My email subject" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account"
```

on your `<messaging:emailTemplate>` component

To refer to the Contact's name, you would use

```
{!recipient.firstname} {!recipient.lastName}
```

see the [VF doc here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_email_templates_creating.htm).